# Wicket: How to distinguish between render caused by certain ajax target and other renders

Tags: wicket

in my application wicket is the client server and I am having a problem,I have two scenarios where the wicket asks from the server for info

1. read
2. read after update

i need to distinguish between the two cases , i want somethnig like

```
  READ_OR_READ_AFTER_UPDATE paramter = READ_OR_READ_AFTER_UPDATE.READ; 
  ajaxRequestTarget.add(compToRender,parmeter);
```

is there a way to send the component value and treat the value inserted in prior call inside this component getModel , or before render...

Comment: Why? What is your usecase? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the current request is Ajax by:
if (RequestCycle.get().find(AjaxRequestTarget.class) != null) { Ajax } else {non-Ajax}

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i understand you correctly. Maybe this is what you want:

In your component set a variable for this

```
public Boolean isUpdated = Boolean.FALSE;
```

In your method where you perform the "update" set this variable to `Boolean.TRUE`;

In your components `onConfigure()` method overide and perform what you want:

```
 @Override
 protected void onConfigure() {
    super.onConfigure();
    if (isUpdated){
       //do this
    } else {
       //do that
    }
 }
```